# Слияние голов в hg

Tags: mercurial, hg

Нужно как-то сделать `hg merge`, работаю с ним первый раз, по работе пришлось. Есть три головы:

```
набор изм-й:   793:a9538d998c96
метка:         tip
автор:         ...
дата:          Wed Apr 08 16:19:52 2015 +0300
сводка:        Disable clock

набор изм-й:   786:a551899dab0e
автор:          ...
дата:          Mon Mar 23 12:22:53 2015 +0200
сводка:        ZaWeb update

набор изм-й:   783:d3efe0bd461c
родитель:      781:69b8c5cadf43
автор:         ...
дата:          Mon Mar 23 13:11:41 2015 +0300
сводка:        erver commit
```

Как я понял, и как мне сказали, их надо смерджить. Делаю `hg merge`: 
**прервано: ветка 'default' имеет 3 голов(ы) - явно укажите ревизию для слияния**

как быть и что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала мерджите первые две головы, потом следующие и так далее.

```
  hg merge -r 786
  hg commit
  hg merge -r 783
```

Подробнее:

- http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeMultipleHeads (англ.)